tensorflow wants CNN's output to be the same shape as input
I'm coding a CNN model for analysis of time series recording from 16 channels, 60000 samples each. I want the output to be a 1x4 vector of some specific values. The problem is tensorflow wants the output to be the same shape as input (It can't be as 60000 samples is a single record).
I would like to ask you why it doesn't work? The code is included below. Don't mind very specific kernel shapes - I'm experimenting and it is highly work in progress. Based on my research I guess it has to do with input shape of first layer, but I don't know how to change this as I want this input to be treaded as kind of an image
    model = keras.Sequential([

            keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (500, 8), strides = (10, 2), input_shape=(60000, 16, 1)), #conv1D - filters, kernel size, activation, input shape
            keras.layers.BatchNormalization(), #batch normalization
            keras.layers.Activation('relu'),  # Separate activation layer

            keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1, 2)),
            keras.layers.Flatten(),

            keras.layers.Dense(640, activation = 'sigmoid'),
            keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),

            keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='sigmoid'),
            keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),

            keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='sigmoid'),
            keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),

            keras.layers.Dense(4, activation = 'sigmoid')

        ])

It produces:
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous. Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.'x' sizes: 60000
'y' sizes: 4


Forgot to mention - Im 90% sure tf is configured to be channels-last

Actually I might have a small step forward. "Sampled" in my understanding is digitized with given step, but tf probably means separate records with target value desired for each (60000 values). Still dont know how to reshape it, to make it work. I have 184 matrices with shape 60000x16, and target is 184x4. tf is 100% configured channels-last

This is related to how you provide the data to the model, you cannot just give single (x,y) samples, it has to be batches i.e. shape b x 60000 x 16 x 1 for x and b x 4 for y.
